# gob: interface is only registered on Encode but not on Decode

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm working on an appengine app using the datastore. I'm attempting to gob
encode an interface and store it into the datastore. But when I try to load from
the datastore, I get the error:

```
gob: name not registered for interface: "main27155.strand"
```

The peculiar thing is that the `load()` method starts working after having
called the `save()` method. It no longer returns an error, and everything saved
in the datastore is loaded as expected. But when I restart the intance, the
`load()` method stops working again.

The load and save methods I mention refer to the methods defined by the
`datastore.PropertyLoadSaver` interface

From the looks of it, it seems like a problem with registering the
type/interfaces with gob, but I have exactly the same `gob.Register()` calls in
both the `load()` and `save()` methods.

I even tried removing the `gob.Register()` calls from both load and save methods
and adding it to `init()`. The exact same behavior was observed.

How can I load my datastore on a cold start?

```
type bio struct {¬                          
    Id       string¬                        
    Hp       int¬                           
    godie    chan bool //should be buffered¬
    dam      chan int¬                      
    Genetics dna¬                           
}¬                                          

type dna interface {
    decode() mRNA
    Get(int) trait
    Set(int, trait)
    Duplicate() dna
    Len() int
}
type trait interface {
    mutate() trait
}

// implements dna{}
type strand []trait

// implements trait{}
type tdecoration string
type color struct {
    None bool // If true, colors are not shown in theme
    Bg   bool // If true, color is a background color
    R    int  // 0-255
    G    int
    B    int
}
```

.

```
func start(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)

    var bs []bio
    if _, err := datastore.NewQuery("bio").GetAll(c, &bs); err != nil {
        log.Println("bs is len: ", len(bs))
        return err
    }

    ...
    return nil
}

func stop(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    log.Println("Saving top 20 colors")
    var k []*datastore.Key
    var bs []*bio
    stat := getStats()
    for i, b := range stat.Leaderboard {
        k = append(k, datastore.NewKey(c, "bio", b.Id, 0, nil))
        bv := b
        bs = append(bs, &bv)
        // At most 20 bios survive across reboots
        if i > 178 {
            break
        }
    }

    // Assemble slice of keys for deletion
    dk, err := datastore.NewQuery("bio").KeysOnly().GetAll(c, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Query error: %s", err.Error()))
    }

    fn := func(c appengine.Context) error {
        // Delete all old entries
        err := datastore.DeleteMulti(c, dk)
        if err != nil {
            return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Delete error: %s", err.Error()))
        }

        // save the elite in the datastore
        _, err = datastore.PutMulti(c, k, bs)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return nil
    }

    return datastore.RunInTransaction(c, fn, &datastore.TransactionOptions{XG: true})
}

// satisfy datastore PropertyLoadSaver interface ===============================

func (b *bio) Load(c <-chan datastore.Property) error {
    gob.Register(&color{})
    gob.Register(new(tdecoration))
    var str strand
    gob.Register(str)

    tmp := struct {
        Id     string
        Hp     int
        Gengob []byte
    }{}
    if err := datastore.LoadStruct(&tmp, c); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    b.Id = tmp.Id
    b.Hp = tmp.Hp

    return gob.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(string(tmp.Gengob))).Decode(&(b.Genetics))
}
func (b *bio) Save(c chan<- datastore.Property) error {
    defer close(c)
    gob.Register(&color{})
    gob.Register(new(tdecoration))
    var str strand
    gob.Register(str)

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    gen := b.Genetics
    if err := gob.NewEncoder(&buf).Encode(&gen); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    dp := []datastore.Property{
        {Name: "Id", Value: b.Id},
        {Name: "Hp", Value: int64(b.Hp)},
        {Name: "Gengob", Value: buf.Bytes(), NoIndex: true},
    }
    for _, p := range dp {
        c <- p
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Additional info:** This behavior was not present before I stuffed the datastore
calls in `stop()` into `datastore.RunInTransaction()`

Comment: Perhaps it's an issue with the type not being an exported one? I haven't worked with gob in ages so I'm rusty about how it works.

Comment: I'd second Not_a_Golfer's suspicion: From the documentation of encoding/gib: "Structs encode and decode only exported fields.". As this probably has *nothing* to do with appengine, HTTP requests or the datastore: Could you produce an example runnable in the playground?

Comment: The gob package encodes unexported types just fine. [Example](http://play.golang.org/p/-lu435K4Zt).  OP, please check that you are starting the server after making the changes.

Comment: Call `gob.Register()` *once* in your programs `init()` function.

Comment: @BravadaZadada The datastore entries were already saved from the previous runs. That was verified by going to the admin console in the appengine sdk local development server.

Comment: @elithrar I already experimented with that. I took the calls out of `load()` and `save()` and put them in the beginning of `init()` with the same result. Same behavior.

Comment: Can you also post/add the type definition for `*b` (which I assume is global and not inside a function)

Comment: It looks like type `strand` was registered with the package name `main27155`.  Is that a package in your application?  If `main27155` is an AppEngine generated package name, then use gob.RegisterName("main.srand", srand) to force a fixed name. Clear any existing saved data to eliminate confusion with possible bad names in the data.  Call gob.Register() once in init() as stated earlier.

Comment: @elithrar Just added the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register all types an in init() functions using [RegisterName()](http://godoc.org/encoding/gob#RegisterName).  Delete all existing data from the store and you should be good to go.

App Engine generates a mangled name for the main package every time the application is built. The name generated by [Register()](http://godoc.org/encoding/gob#Register) includes this mangled package name. Any gobs encoded with the mangled name will only be readable using the same build of the app. If you cause the application to be rebuilt by modifying the code, then the app will not be able to decode gobs stored previously.

Comment: You were right about `RegisterName()` I don't know why it didn't work before. Thanks!